# How can i solve gazebo sdf warning?

Tags: ros, gazebo-simu

I use UBUNTU 20.04 and ROS foxy. gazebo version is 11.14.
i just run this command
[image]

and i have this issue:

```
[gzserver-1] Warning [parser.cc:833] XML Attribute[version] in element[s d f] not defined in S D F, ignoring.
```

I reinstall gazebo a few times . I don't have this problem while i use gazebo 11.11 I tried install that version but i couldn't. Please help

Comment: which ros2 distro you are using?

Comment: i use ros2 foxy

Comment: I am getting the same error in ros2 galactic, empty world gets launched but the turtlebot3 is not spawning

Comment: I change my ROS version to humble. i don't have issue like this now. Also i use Ubuntu 22.04 now. Probably it's all about version error. i didn't use galactic so i don't know well but did you try 2d pose estimate? can you share screenshots?